# Not seeing deposit transaction in Electrum from BTCPayServer after invoice has been paid

Tags: electrum, payment-processors

I have imported my xpub into btcpayserver store and created some invoices and paid them. The btcpayserver wallet shows the balance from the invoices as having been paid.

However when I look at Electrum I do NOT see these deposits.

I have increased my gap limit to 100, but still nothing. All I see is my outgoing transactions when I tested the invoice api and paid the invoices. The bitcoin is not coming back to the wallet.

Comment: Assuming the payment did confirm in a block: Can you confirm that the address you paid to is present in the electrum wallet? If it is, then your electrum wallet must  not be in sync. If it isn’t, I would guess either a derivation path issue, or a gap limit issue (but it seems like you addressed that).

Comment: I see the payment if i pay from coinbase to BPS address, then it shows in Electrum and Exodus but only if I associate the wallet to BPS using zpub. If I use the same wallet to pay the invoice, the deposit never shows.